# threejs mirrored orbitcontrol without zooming

Tags: three.js

I have 2 scene with 2 orbit controls,
when the main scene rotates, aid scene should also rotate
when the main scene zoom / pan, aid scene should not zoom / pan.

it seems like rotate moves camera's position and rotation, which was copied to aid scene's camera position / rotation. when zooming, rotation of xyz is not changed.

so, how can the aid scene copy only the rotation of the main scene but not the zooming / paning?

Comment: Add a formula to the animate() loop. aid.scene.rotation.x = main.scene.rotation.x; aid.scene.rotation.y = main.scene.rotation.y; etc..

Comment: But i guess you are not rotating a scene, but changing camera position and rotation. Solution will be the same for camera object. set the second scene camera the same pos and rot params as a first scene camera.

Comment: camera is not zoom or pan, camera is moving close to its target when you make "zoom".

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague and implies knowledge of code that cannot be seen. But I suggest that you just turn off  zoom control in your OrbitController, e.g. `oControl.enableZoom=false;`  (if your orbit controller is assigned to var "oControl")

Comment: I didn't post any code because mirroring the view is basically copying control A's position & rotation to control B, thus when you rotate, turn, pan control A, control B is doing exactly the same (mirroring).